# Does anybody know how to insert a complete jquery plugin into a wordpress elementor-page?

Tags: plugins, javascript, jquery

I tried to implement a jquery plugin into a wp-page which gets displayed on an elementor page.
Here is [the link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Responsive-Diagonal-Slider-Plugin-With-jQuery-CSS3-Skewed-Slider.html) to the plugin.

**What I have tried so far:**

**1.** I loaded the jquery-file via plugin (via functions.php it didn't work).
-> it loads in head: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AikSNhBAk4tevjHlEeV67BifIivC

I am not sure about the path, if it's correct and if it's even necessary on wordpress anymore.
**2.** I inserted the html and css (this was the easy part).
**3.** I inserted ( +replaced '$' with 'jquery' ) and loaded the core.js via functions.php
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AikSNhBAk4tevjPkE6V7KdVSICTh

That's how far I could go, I know my steps are not correct, but I don't know to which folder I should upload the files (exact structure) and how I should call the js files on elementor.
The html and css part work already.

I'd like to understand how to do that correctly - if you have any good advice for me.
Thank you.

Comment: Does really nobody know where to add the downloaded folder in wordpress?
I don't know the exact structure so I am still struggling to implement the jquery plugin.
  
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just made a wordpress plugin out of the jquery plugin, inserted shortcodes and changed the way of adding the images.
This solved all mentioned issues.